# SETW not a function

Tags: c++

I have a problem
I'm using C++

And here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void balloon(){ //start void
    int num, N[10], x, y, z,temp,setw;

    cout<<"How many number would you like to sort? ";
    cin>>num;
    cout<<"Input the "<<num<<" numbers:"<<endl;

    for(x=0;x<num;x++)
        cin>>N[x];

    for(x=0;x<num;x++)
    {
        for(y=0;y<num-x;y++)
        { 
            if(N[x] > N[x+y])
            { 
                temp=N[x];
                N[x] =N[x+y];
                N[x+y]=temp;
            }
        }

        cout<<"pass "<<x+1<<"] ";

        for(z=0;z<num;z++)
        {
            cout<<setw(5)<<N[z];
        }

    cout<<endl;

    }

}//end void
```

I get a error that setw is not a function
Please help me and if you ever found some more errors please advice me
Thanks

Comment: You're [missing a header](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/).

Comment: You have also declared `setw` as an `int` variable on line 5.

Comment: Read the documentation for the language features that you use. Don't just randomly guess.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, standard I/O manipulators are declared in standard header `<iomanip>`. You are supposed to include it, if you want to use them.

Secondly, you declared you own local variable `setw` (what for?) and thus hid the standard `setw`. Either remove your own declaration or use qualified name `std::setw` to refer to the standard one.

Answer (score 0):

> I get a error that setw is not a function

Well, it's not, because you declared it to be an `int`. Don't do that.

`#include <iomanip>` to get `std::setw`.